# What difference is awaited if I time these 2 functions?

Tags: c, algorithm, time, buffer

I can use C code and/or system program e.g. time to measure the difference of the 2 functions but what would we expect? Just because the ratio is 1:1024 doesn't mean buffered is 1024 times faster or does it?

```
#define SIZE 1024 /* read 1024 bytes at a time */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void info(char file_name[]);
    void buffered(char file_name[]);

    info("/proc/scsi/scsi"); /* read a byte at a time */
    buffered("/proc/cpuinfo"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    return 0;
}

void info(char file_name[])
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    // read mode
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void buffered(char file_name[])
{
    char buf[SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    size_t nread;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp) {
        while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp)) > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
        }
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            /* to do: deal with error */
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

How much should I buffer?

### Update

I added a timer that says the difference is large:

```
$ cc cpu-disk-info.c
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~$ ./a.out 
Unbuffered: 0.040000 seconds
Buffered: 0.000000 seconds
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 1024 /* read 1024 bytes at a time */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void info(char file_name[]);
    void buffered(char file_name[]);
    clock_t toc;
    clock_t tic = clock();
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    toc = clock();
    printf("Unbuffered: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    tic = clock();    
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    toc = clock();
    printf("Buffered: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);   
    return 0;
}

void info(char file_name[])
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    // read mode
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        //putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void buffered(char file_name[])
{
    char buf[SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    size_t nread;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp) {
        while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp)) > 0)
    {
            //fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
    }
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            /* to do: deal with error */
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

### Test 2

According to this test, the buffered i/o is 19 times faster(?) than the unbuffered i/o.

```
Unbuffered: 0.190000 seconds
Buffered: 0.010000 seconds
```

Source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 1024 /* read 1024 bytes at a time */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void info(char file_name[]);
    void buffered(char file_name[]);
    clock_t toc;
    clock_t tic = clock();
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    info("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read a byte at a time */
    toc = clock();
    printf("Unbuffered: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    tic = clock();    
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    buffered("Cube.001.skeleton.xml"); /* read 1024 bytes at a time */
    toc = clock();
    printf("Buffered: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);   
    return 0;
}

void info(char file_name[])
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    // read mode
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        //putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void buffered(char file_name[])
{
    char buf[SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    size_t nread;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp) {
        while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp)) > 0)
    {
            //fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
    }
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            /* to do: deal with error */
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you time them? I'm always interested in what we expect vs what actually happens.

Comment: @DougRamsey I added a timing that says the difference is large. Thanks for the comment. I have no theoretical analysis but a maesurement in the C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some difference, but not with a factor of 1024. In your `info()` function, you are not buffering, but the I/O library is. Even if the I/O library were not buffering, the Operating System is probably buffering.

Also, since you are writing the data to the standard output, the bottleneck might be precisely there. Printing characters to a "console" (or "terminal") window in a graphic environment is surprisingly slow. Try writing to disc, or nowhere at all. You will probably get different results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added a test that says the difference is large but it doesn't say the factor. In the test I commented out the actual writing to standard output.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to open the same file with both functions ;-)

Comment: In the test I let both functions handle the same data size. I did it 5 times so that buffered i/o will get a value > 0 and it does. It says buffered i/o is about 19 times faster than unbuffered according to the test.